# Drawing Projection of the Plane

Tags: linear-algebra, analytic-geometry

- Can you draw that projection of $x=(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ to the plane $\pi$ through $0$ orthogonal to $u=(1,1,1)$?

I want to see as a picure this but I couldn't draw, can you help?

Comment: Do you know how to draw the plane?

Comment: @angryavian I know how to draw the plane?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the drawing..........................

[image]

Comment: The link says 'webpage not available'.

Comment: Which link? The picture is embedded in the answer.

Comment: I don't see the picture When I click this ''enter image description here'', then I see ''webpage not available'.

Comment: Could be a problem with your web browser. Can you see the images in the other questions and answers on this site?

Comment: I don't see images in the other questions and answers on this site. I use Google Chrome on my computer and mobile application on the my phone (Huawei, Android), so I still don't see

Comment: Try with another browser, e.g. Mozilla Firefox.

Comment: Anyway, here's the link to the image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgkdg.png

Comment: the link doesn't work...